# Issue concerning NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, exists

I need to find the names and IDs of all clients who haven't lend a book from the category where the category name has the letters 'non' in it. I have this code:

```
SELECT CLIENT.clientname, CLIENT.client_id
FROM CLIENT
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM LEND
  WHERE CLIENT.client_id = LEND.client_id
  AND CATEGORY.category like '%non%'
)
```

What is wrong with this code? I have been searching for days to write the right code for this and I'm not sure if it's even possible (though I'm pretty sure I'll be proven wrong immediately). I'm absolutely stuck at this one. My code always shows every lent book WITH the lent books that have the category 'non' in it.

EDIT: The entire database structure has been added here:

- Author (consists of AuthorID and AuthorName)
- Books (BookID, AuthorID, Year, Title, CategoryID, PublisherID)
- Category (CategoryID, CategoryName)
- Client (ClientID, ClientName, Place)
- Publisher (PublisherID, PublisherName)
- Lend (Number, BookID, Date, ClientID)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like you might be missing a join between `lend` and `category` in the subquery.

Comment: You're referencing `CATEGORY` in your subquery without having scoped it at all.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably missing a JOIN with the `CATEGORY` table. I rewrote que query to use the `NOT IN`

```
SELECT  CLIENT.clientname, CLIENT.client_id
FROM    CLIENT
WHERE   CLIENT.client_id NOT IN
(
    SELECT  DISTINCT LEND.client_id
    FROM    LEND
    JOIN    CATEGORY
        ON  LEND.category_id = CATEGORY.category_id
    WHERE   CATEGORY.category like '%non%'
)
```

Comment: I have never learned what even is or how to use JOIN, DISTINCT or ON before. The code still doesn't work, because LEND.category_id doesn't exist in the table LEND.

Comment: Well, I had to guess the column name; why don't you [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33063663/edit) the question and add the table schema?

Comment: I can't correct you on your code, because I don't know how JOIN works. I've only started writing code maybe about three weeks ago. My teacher never showed me what JOIN was or that it even existed in the first place. I just now discovered that JOIN is taught way, WAY later in the manual, so I don't even know if JOIN is the right way to solve this problem. What I do know is that, when I use all the knowledge I have been taught right now, this problem cannot be solved, it just doesn't work.

Comment: Can't you just put your table structure into the question?

Comment: I will do this immediately.

Answer (score 1):

You need to somehow join the LEND and CATEGORY tables in your sub query.

Without knowing your scheme I cannot tell exactly but the problem is this:

```
SELECT * FROM LEND WHERE CLIENT.client_id = LEND.client_id AND CATEGORY.category like '%non%'
```

You are only selecting from LEND but your condition references CATEGORY in "CATEGORY.category like '%non%'"

EDIT:
Based on the description you have added I guess it should be something like this:

```
SELECT CLIENT.clientname, CLIENT.client_id
FROM CLIENT
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM LEND
  INNER JOIN BOOKS ON LEND.BookID = BOOKS.BookID
  INNER JOIN CATEGORY ON CATEGORY.CategoryID = BOOKS.CategoryID
  WHERE CLIENT.client_id = LEND.client_id
  AND CATEGORY.CategoryName like '%non%'
)
```

Might vary a little depending on the database. Some databases are case sensitive.

Comment: When I put in your code, I get the following error: "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'non-fictie' to data type int." I am working in the Dutch language, hence the "non-fictie" part. In the table CATEGORY of my database, there are only three entries: "1: Non-Fictie, 2: Fictie, 3: Wetenschappelijk (meaning 'Scientific')". The problem is that I can't just ask TSQL to leave out 'Non-fictie' because the question literally states to leave out the letters 'non'. I'll certainly come back tomorrow to further figure out how to solve this one, I really want to understand!